# How to access session variable from response object in django test?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-testing, django-sessions

How can i access session variable using response object in django test.

```
def test(self):    
    postdata={'user':'staff'}
    self.client.login(username='vishnu',password='vishnu@12345')
    session=self.client.session
    session['user']='manager'
    session.save()

    response=self.client.post(reverse('userhome'),postdata)
    self.assertEqual(session['user'],'staff')
```

This test fails when run. In the above test, after calling post request the session variable 'user' will change to staff. How do i check the change? `session['user']` gives same result after request. However in the view function `request.session['user']` gives exact result.

How can i access session data from response?

Comment: Please show us the view code that is modifying the session.

Comment: View code just contain assignment only `request.session['user']=request.POST['user']`

Answer (score 0):

Checking the final session state in `self.client.session` is working for me.  `self.client` and `response.client` are the same object, so you could use `response.client.session` if that better signals intent:

```py
def test(self):    
    postdata={'user':'staff'}
    self.client.login(username='vishnu',password='vishnu@12345')
    session=self.client.session
    session['user']='manager'
    session.save()
    response=self.client.post(reverse('userhome'),postdata)

    self.assertIn('user', self.client.session)
    self.assertEqual(self.client.session['user'], 'staff')

    self.assertIn('user', response.client.session)
    self.assertEqual(response.client.session['user'], 'staff')
```

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#persistent-state) would seem to suggest that this wouldn't work: "To modify the session and then save it, it must be stored in a variable first (because a new SessionStore is created every time this property is accessed)."  But I guess that's only true of setting the session before sending a request?  Not sure, but it could use some clarification.